# Retrieve distinct ids from hive?

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

I have a data as follows:

### id        name         state

1         kim           ny
1         danny         nj
1         kim           in
2         tom           pa
2         sam           ca
3         matt          oh
4         kyle          oh

I need to get distinct ids and all the remaining data.

output:

### id       name         state

1         kim           ny
2         tom           pa
3         matt          oh
4         kyle          oh

I have used "select distinct(id), name, state from population" and the output i'm getting is same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the same as your input because Distinct works on all the columns in your select list, not just the one in the parenthesis.  To get a distinct list of IDs and names you could Group by those two columns.

```
CREATE table #tmp (ID INT, name VARCHAR(10), State VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1, 'kim', 'ny')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1, 'kim', 'nj')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1, 'kim', 'in')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(2, 'tom', 'pa')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(2, 'tom', 'ca')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(3, 'matt', 'oh')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(4, 'kyle', 'oh')


SELECT ID, name, COUNT(*) AS 'State_Count' FROM #tmp
GROUP BY ID, name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. What if the data is as below:             1 kim ny,  1 danny nj ,  1 kim in,   2 tom pa,    2 sam ca,   3 matt oh

Comment: Sorry I jus modified the question.

Comment: So you want to see "TOM" and "PA" for ID 2.  What is your logic for selecting that over "SAM" and "CA"?  They come first in your list?  you could do something with MIN() function, but they would return the first alphabetical result and if you used it for multiple columns you would get data from different rows.

Comment: I'm only interested in the distinct "id" as of now. I want to retrive distinct id along with the remaining two columns (the name & state columns can be anything).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get distinct ids so you should only select it like that:

```
select distinct(id) from population;
```

You cannot simply use distinct id and expect to get other columns. Can you describe what kind of output you trying to get?

Comment: This is the output i'm trying to get:
1 kim ny,    2 tom pa,       3 matt oh,       4 kyle oh

Comment: Hmm... I get it, but how could hive predict that you want the first row it has.  That's why you should collect them and get first element in array. 

select id, collect_list(name)[0], collect_list(state)[0] from population group by id;

Comment: I'm only interested in the distinct "id" as of now. I want to retrive distinct id along with the remaining two columns (the name & state columns can be anything).

Thank you